# Processes within a multiprocessing.Pool exhibit very different performance when using map()

Tags: python, scipy, multiprocessing

I'm looking to solve a differential equation `N` times, each time with
a different set of parameters. `multiprocessing` therefore sounds like
the right tool for the job:let's define a `solve` function that does
the actual work of computing the solution and use a
`multiprocessing.Pool` with `map` to distribute the work among several
processes.

Here the code with `N=8` and 2 processes:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time
import numpy as np

from bench import init_model, get_initial_solution

model = init_model()
sol_init = get_initial_solution(model, np.linspace(0, 1, 2), {"Current": 0.67})

Nsteps = 10
step_solver = model.default_solver

def solve(ind):
    st = time.time()
    step_solution = sol_init
    for step in range(0, Nsteps):
        step_solution = step_solver.step(
            step_solution, 
            model, 
            dt=1, 
            npts=2, 
            inputs={"Current": 2.0}, 
            save=False
    )
    return f"Task {ind} took {time.time() - st:.2f}s"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Pool(processes=2) as p:
        times = p.map(solve, np.arange(1, 9))
        print("\n".join(times))
```

For debugging purposes, `solve` does not return the solution, but
instead the time spent by the process inside the function.

Executing the above (my computer has 4 cores), I get:

```sh
Task 1 took 4.41s
Task 2 took 5.59s
Task 3 took 1.67s
Task 4 took 0.62s
Task 5 took 0.61s
Task 6 took 0.72s
Task 7 took 0.68s
Task 8 took 0.53s
```

As you can see the time spent in the function `solve` varies widely
across the process pool, and across a large range of values.
Note that these result's aren't deterministic. *i.e* if I executed
the above script again, a very different set of times would be
observed.  There is no reason for this randomness though, the amount
of work to be done is the same across processes and executions.

Let's profile the execution of the processes to get a bit more
information about what's going on in there.

```py
import cProfile
import pstats

def profile(ind):
    cProfile.runctx("solve(ind)", globals(), locals(), "report_"+str(ind)+".txt")

with Pool(processes=2) as p:
    times = p.map(profile, np.arange(1,9))

for ind in range(1,9):
    stats = pstats.Stats("report_"+str(ind)+".txt").strip_dirs()
    stats.sort_stats("cumulative")
    stats.print_stats(11)
```

For instance if we look at the reports for tasks 1 and 7:

```sh
Thu Oct 29 18:07:18 2020    report_1.txt

         75858 function calls (75426 primitive calls) in 0.895 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time
   List reduced from 249 to 11 due to restriction <11>

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.895    0.895 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.895    0.895 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.895    0.895 python-1mtcbY:15(solve)
       10    0.001    0.000    0.895    0.090 base_solver.py:712(step)
       10    0.001    0.000    0.892    0.089 scipy_solver.py:35(_integrate)
       10    0.003    0.000    0.889    0.089 ivp.py:156(solve_ivp)
       88    0.001    0.000    0.738    0.008 base.py:159(step)
       88    0.010    0.000    0.738    0.008 bdf.py:296(_step_impl)
       45    0.000    0.000    0.668    0.015 bdf.py:216(lu)
       45    0.666    0.015    0.668    0.015 decomp_lu.py:15(lu_factor)
     1284    0.003    0.000    0.139    0.000 base_solver.py:906(__call__)


Thu Oct 29 18:07:27 2020    report_7.txt

         75831 function calls (75399 primitive calls) in 6.773 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time
   List reduced from 244 to 11 due to restriction <11>

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    6.773    6.773 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.000    0.000    6.773    6.773 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    6.773    6.773 python-1mtcbY:15(solve)
       10    0.001    0.000    6.773    0.677 base_solver.py:712(step)
       10    0.000    0.000    6.770    0.677 scipy_solver.py:35(_integrate)
       10    0.002    0.000    6.769    0.677 ivp.py:156(solve_ivp)
       88    0.001    0.000    6.612    0.075 base.py:159(step)
       88    0.011    0.000    6.612    0.075 bdf.py:296(_step_impl)
       45    0.000    0.000    6.520    0.145 bdf.py:216(lu)
       45    6.519    0.145    6.520    0.145 decomp_lu.py:15(lu_factor)
     1284    0.003    0.000    0.146    0.000 base_solver.py:906(__call__)
```

The above tells us that in the two cases (it is the case for all
tasks), the process spends the most of its lifetime inside Scipy's
`lu_factor`. The suprising bit however (at least surprising to me) is
that the time spent in `lu_factor` varies - widely - across tasks. This is
what I would like to understand.

Answer (score 0):

presumably this is due to global mutable state; the first two tasks are "slow" which corresponds to the number of processes in the pool.

I'd suggest making things more deterministic by moving

```py
model = init_model()
sol_init = get_initial_solution(model, np.linspace(0, 1, 2), {"Current": 0.67})
```

inside `solve`

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for  the suggestion! This two lines represent quite a signifiacant overhead, and this work would have to be done 4 times per process (8 tasks and 2 processes). So the overall wall time is increased.  Even then, the time per task varies a lot, for instance:
`
Task 1 took 2.67s
Task 2 took 3.22s
Task 3 took 5.45s
Task 4 took 5.33s
Task 5 took 8.03s
Task 6 took 7.91s
Task 7 took 3.66s
Task 8 took 3.29s
`

Comment: I guess it depends why you're trying to parallelise this code, at the moment it seems somewhat pointless evolving the state from one starting point four times.  also note that windows vs unix behaviour is different here, under unix you'll just do the init once, windows you'll do it three times.  also might be worth looking into how your BLAS library is configured, i.e. is it trying to parallelise across cores (hence each python process is fighting for time)

Comment: So I checked, and indeed decomposing a large array using scipy's `lu_factor` utilizes the four cores on my computer. So I suppose this explains the poor performance of the multiprocessing code! As you said the processes are presumably fighting for resources. I'll try with the parallelization from LAPACK disabled then.

Answer (score 0):

`lu_factor` is a wrapper around LAPACK's `getrf` routines, which itself relies on the BLAS. In my case, the underlying BLAS implementation is OpenBlas, provided inside the scipy wheel when installing scipy from PyPI with `pip`.
As Sam Mason suggested, running `lu_factor` utilizes the four cores on my machine, because the underlying OpenBLAS is multithreaded.
Disabling multithreading for OpenBLAS with `export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1` largely solves the he performance issues described above. Indeed, running the same script with 2 processes again:

```
Task 1 took 0.19s
Task 2 took 0.19s
Task 3 took 0.18s
Task 4 took 0.18s
Task 5 took 0.18s
Task 6 took 0.18s
Task 7 took 0.18s
Task 8 took 0.18s
```

I note that the first two tasks are consistently slightly (around 10%) slower than the rest, which may be linked to Sam Mason's original answer about the impact of global mutable state, although I don't fully understand why at this point.